# Recover Deleted User Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I have deleted user by "Delete user folder (safe)" mode in Mac OS X V 10.7.5. Please, don't ask me why, but now I need it.

I am googling it, but nothing usefull. I found some folders with name like "6 17-11-10-062.0", "6 17-11-10-062.0", "6 17-31-31-784.0" and "6.0" in my trash. What is it?

How can I recover user data? What program can help me? Sorry for my English. Thaks :)

Comment: There used to be a dmg formed of the user folder if it was a safe delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the "Delete the home folder" with "Erase home folder securely" option, there's no way to recover it. If you had not chosen the "Erase ... securely" option (and not done much else with the computer after deleting the account), you might've been able to use data recovery software to find & recover at least some of the files. But what the "... securely" option does is to overwrite the deleted files to make sure they're *really really* gone and unrecoverable. That's what they mean by secure deletion.

There's a slight possibility that you might be able to use data recovery software to find traces of files that were deleted normally (insecurely) from the account *before* the account itself was deleted. But I wouldn't expect to find much, and what you would find would be (by definition) old versions and other things you considered unimportant.

If you are interested in trying to do data recovery, **stop using the computer immediately**. Shut it down and use some other computer to research your options ([this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/174719/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-mac-os-x) is a good place to start). The more you use the computer, the more of the old files will be unrecoverable because the space they were stored in is continuously getting reused for new files, and once it's reused, whatever was there before is gone.

I don't know what the folders you found in your trash are, but I'm pretty sure they're nothing to do with the deleted account. Sorry, but unless you have a backup, I think you're not going to be able to get much of anything.